# How to get the value of variable out of two async functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, asynchronous

I want to write a code in which, there is a array of few currencies. I want to get rates for the combinations of these currencies in the array. 
i.e. If I have a array like this:
['USD','AUD','GBP'], then I want to get the value of conversions like:
USD->AUD, USD->GBP, AUD->USD, AUD->GBP, GBP->USD, GBP->AUD. To get the live currency rates I have used currency api at here: http://currency-api.appspot.com
Because I have a sort of repetition I have used for loop to create the urls for the ajax request for json. After I have created the url's I have saved them to ur array, and also the conversion name in curr array, so that I can use the same index to refer to the ur array and curr array.

NOW COMES THE TRICKY PART

to loop through the urls and get the live currency values for each currency conversions I have used $.each, and inside $.each I have $.ajax.
Now after I have got the value of the I have stored it to an array - an_array.

Finally at the end(out of the $.end and $.ajax), when I am trying to print the values of an_array, it is empty.

```
var currencies = ['AUD','USD','INR','GBP'];
var ur = [];
var curr = [];
var curr_val = [];
var an_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < currencies.length; j++) {
    if (i != j) {
      cont = 'https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/' + currencies[i] + '/' + currencies[j] + '.jsonp';
      tex = currencies[i] + ' ' + currencies[j]
      curr.push(tex);
      ur.push(cont);
    }
  }
}

$.each(ur, function (index, value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: value,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {amount: '1.00'},
    success: function (response) {
      result = response.rate;
      an_array.push(result);
    }
  });
});

console.log(an_array)
/*This is returning [], but should return array with values. 
 I can't move this line from here, to inside, 
 I have logged it here because I want to check whether its working, 
 I want to perform calculations for the values coming out from here.*/
```

**NOTE:1) I have already tried the .done() method of ajax

       2) I think this is an async issue, and I also tried with the callback functions for which the console returned that, there is not callback function error**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anivarth/hz38zL0v/9/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ur = [];
var curr = [];
var curr_val = [];
var an_array = [];

var calculationWithResult = function( myArrayForCalculation ){
 
  // Make your calculation here
  console.log( 'Every call has been made : ' , myArrayForCalculation );
  
}

for(var i=0;i<currencies.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<currencies.length;j++){
        if(i!=j){
            cont = 'https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/'+currencies[i]+'/'+currencies[j]+'.jsonp';
            tex = currencies[i]+' '+currencies[j]
            curr.push(tex);
            ur.push(cont);
            }
        }
    }

var numberOfURL = ur.length;
console.log('we wait for '  + numberOfURL + ' ajax call ');

$.each(ur,function(index,value){
     $.ajax({
             url: value,
             dataType: "jsonp",
             data: {amount: '1.00'},
             success: function(response) {
               
               numberOfURL = numberOfURL-1
               console.log('rest of ajaxCall : ' + numberOfURL); 
               
               result = response.rate;
               an_array.push(result);
                      
               if(numberOfURL===0) calculationWithResult( result ); // make your stuff
               
               console.log(an_array);//<-------HERE
             }//                               |
              //                               |
              //                               |
 });//                                         |
});//                                          |
//                                             |     
//console.log(an_array) |----------------- MOVE THIS
```

Comment: but what if I want to do further calculations with the data??

Comment: Do the calculation in the success or create a new function ! i will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Does my modification helped you ? need you something else ?

Comment: What if I had to use it outside the $.each, as same as my code??

Comment: I am asking for use of outside of $.each function because, after I have got the array completed, then I have to form equations in linear programming, for currency arbitrage problem...

Comment: i have updated my answer to relfect what you nedd, check it and tell if it is ok !

Comment: Yah got it, I will compute with the above code but can't we use the variable outside the $.each even if we make any changes???

Comment: This depend of the'scope' of the variable, but like you use it you can ! each function can reach the variable so it can modify it !

Comment: a very complete documentation about that : [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely an async issue. You can use jQuery deferreds to do this easily.

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(ur, function(value, index) {
  return $.ajax(...) /* without "success" */
}).then(function(results) {
  ...
  console.log(...);
});
```

Behind the scenes, `when` counts your completions, and when all of the requests have completed, executes the `then` handler.

The low-tech solution, without using deferreds, is to do it all manually:

```
var totalAjaxCalls = ur.length;

$.each(ur, ...
  ...
    success: function(response) {
      result = response.rate;
      an_array.push(result);
      if (!(--totalAjaxCalls)) {
        console.log("All results available");
        console.log(results);
      }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: `$.ajax` returns a `Deferred`. `$.map` transforms `ur` into a list of `Deferred` objects. `$.when` takes multiple `Deferred` arguments and produces a `Deferred` which will not resolve until all the input ones resolve. (I might have flubbed syntax somewhere; maybe `$.when.apply($, $.map(...))` because `$.when` seems to want each `Deferred` in a separate argument. I'll edit...)

Comment: `$.when.apply($, [d1, d2...])` is the same as `$.when(d1, d2...)`.

Comment: but I am also using $.each to execute this code...what about that ??

Comment: Don't use `$.each`, move everything into the `$.map` - they are the same thing, only `$.map` returns values whereas `$.each` does not.

Comment: Amadan, can you please edit my code on jsfiddle please, Thank you in advance....Please edit my code on jsfiddle and paste the link. It will help me a lot....thanks...

Comment: Also can I use all the variables outside, the then handler??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hz38zL0v/10/ ; no, the general rule is that you never, ever use any results of async calls outside the callback, or functions that are ultimately called by the callback (unless the values are optional and you test for their presence when you want to use them, and ignore them if they are not there yet).

Comment: Okay @Amadan you suggest me to create an if statement inside the success and then do my computaions there??

Comment: You have a working fiddle in my previous comment. Indeed, you cannot "do your computations" where you have them in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/00qkxko1/1/):

```js
var currencies = { "USD": {},"AUD": {},"GBP": {} };
var currencyValuesLength = Object.keys( currencies ).length * ( Object.keys( currencies ).length - 1 );
// when all done
function whenAllDone() {
    $.each( currencies, function( currency_from, values ) {
        $.each( currencies[ currency_from ], function( currency_to, value ) {
            $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" + currency_from + " -> " + currency_to + " = " + value + "</div>" ) );
        } );
    } );
}
// get values
function getValues() {
    $.each( currencies, function( currency_from, values ) {
        $.each( currencies, function( currency_to, value ) {
            if ( currency_from != currency_to ) {
                $.ajax( {
                 url: "https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/" + currency_from + "/" + currency_to + ".jsonp",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        amount: "1.00"
                    },
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function( response ) {
                        currencies[ currency_from ][ currency_to ] = response.rate;
                        var currentLength = 0;
                        $.each( currencies, function( currency, values_temp ) {
                             currentLength += Object.keys( values_temp ).length;
                        } );
                        if ( currentLength == currencyValuesLength ) {
                            whenAllDone();
                        }
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
    } );
}
// onload
$( function() {
    getValues();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```